# HTML & CSS: two separate issues desire one answer :)

Tags: html, css, layout, fonts, font-face

1)  my fonts are not installed on users computer --> site looks bad.
How can I force the website to look exactly the same on computers that don't have my website fonts installed on their computer (force install or reference an API)

**Note**:

- Answers suggesting to place images are not welcome.
- Answers suggesting google font API - my font (Margot, Alef) are not supported by it.

2) my site uses bootstrap, I've looked in [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) to understand the grid layout but can't seem to make it work. 
I have a background image with some text and wish to have my button position exactly underneath it. this is my code

```
<div class="fullwidthbanner-container overlay-fix">
        <div class="top-overlay"></div>
        <div class="fullwidthbanner" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:0px -800px;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 header-area">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 resp-center header animate animate_aft">
                        <a href="https://www.somewhere.com" class="top-download btn btn-default btn-lg">DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
                    </div>                          
                    <div class="col-sm-4 animate animate_afb">
                        <div class="phone-holder">
                            <img class="phone-in-hand" src="phone-in-hand.png" alt="some video"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Each issue should be a question for itself, right? As per that, for your first issue look at CSS `font-face` rule.

Comment: Run your website on a server.  Also, you have your own CSS along with Bootstrap's if I'm not mistaken.  It would be nice to see yours.  But if you want the button underneath the text (or image) then why not nest (or add) another `row`?

Comment: @UltraSonja the background image contains the text so adding a row doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You can try generate a web font in http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and embed in our site

Answer (score 0):

Use @font-face technique to include fonts user doesn't have locally (you must place the font file in the font folder):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "your-font-name";
    src: url(fonts/your-font-name.ttf);
 }
```

Can read documentation here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: I tried this (with new uninstalled font) but it didn't take any ideas on why? here is my code: `@font-face {
    font-family: Sansation;
    src: url(fonts/sansation/Sansation-Light.ttf);
}` I've wrote this in my css file. and used it like this still in my css defenitions `html, body {font: 10pt 'Sansation', Sansation-Light; line-height: 1!important; margin: 0px!important;padding: 0px!important;border: 0!important;font-size: 100%!important;vertical-align: baseline!important;}`   as well as adding it to  p, h1..h5 etc.

Comment: In your Css File make these changes-> font-family: "sansation", sans-serif; font-size: 10px;

Comment: Also could be the wrong path to the font file (we've all done that).